# What method should I use to know which fds are open after process forks and then execs

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec, ipc

I know that fork and exec family preserve file descriptors after the execution. That behavior is desirable for my needs. Also from the exec manual:

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image
>   with a new process image.

So, If I get it right, after process forks then execs, the program needs additional means of getting to know which fds are open.

What I seek, is simple means of passing fds that will be used(plus fds that need to be closed) to the new process.

As a side note. In Windows you just can see a list fds that are in use by a process. You need to go low level to do that tho.

Comment: Pass them as a process parameter if really needed. Or just close them before `exec`, why do you need them at all?

Comment: If you don't want them open in the child open them with `O_CLOEXEC`, or use `fcntl()` to add the flag after the fact. No need to tell the child to close them.

Comment: @EugeneSh. As  a side work project I'm tasked to do a server. The server will do sockets with epoll and some file I/O based on protocol requests. I'm thinking of such a way, that, will increase file I/O throughput. So the server will accept socket, do a request/response state machine and then fork to process I/O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a system call that just gives you a list of open file descriptors.  But the larger problem you're tackling can be solved in several different ways.  The most typical two ways are:

If the child only handles one client, then simply have it read from its stdin (fd 0) and write to its stdout (fd 1); after forking but before execing, you use `dup2` to reassign the appropriate file descriptors to numbers 0 and 1, leave fd 2 (stderr) alone, and close all the others (or you use `O_CLOEXEC`/`FD_CLOEXEC` in advance so you don't have to do that).  *Some* Unixes have a convenient function called `closefrom` that closes all file descriptors whose numeric value is greater than or equal to its argument, but other Unixes refuse to adopt it, for reasons which I consider entirely bogus.

If the child is talking to a socket or other full-duplex communications channel wrapped up in one file descriptor, you should still assign it as *both* fds 0 and 1, because that way the `stdin` and `stdout` FILE objects can be used normally (up to the point where you need to be using `recvfrom`, `shutdown`, etc, anyway), and because many libraries get confused if any of fds 0, 1, and 2 aren't open.

This strategy provides a good level of parallelism with minimal effort, and allows the child program to be used with `inetd` and similar such multiplexers.

If the child needs to handle more than one client, do *not* assign any of the clients as fds 0 or 1; instead pass a comma-separated list of client sockets to process as a command-line argument.  The child should pay attention to those file descriptors only, and ignore all others, even if they are open.  (You should still make best effort to close all irrelevant fds after forking but before execing.)

Multiplexing I/O for more than one client in the child requires a lot more programming; if you need to go this route, I strongly recommend using an async I/O library that someone has already written for you, such as `libevent` or `libuv`.

---

In circumstances where you really do need to know which fds are open and your parent has given you no clues, you have one bad and nonportable option, and one terrible but portable option.

The bad and nonportable option is to open and scan the directory `/proc/self/fd`.  *If this directory exists*, its entries correspond to the open file descriptors in your process, and their names are the descriptor numbers in decimal.  This is a bad option because you have to loop calling `readdir` and take care to avoid the fd backing the `DIR` handle you're using, and it's nonportable because, as far as I know, *only* Linux implements this special directory, and it might not be available to you even there.

The terrible but portable option is to query the maximum file descriptor number with `getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE)`, and then loop from 0 to that number calling `fcntl(i, F_GETFD)`, which will return a nonnegative number if the fd is open, or a negative number if it's closed (and set errno to EBADF).  This works everywhere, but it can be horrifyingly slow, especially if the maximum file descriptor number is large.

Comment: For such a full answer, I feel obligated to tell more about my task. Me do it as soon as I get home/have free time. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ЯрославМашко I appreciate the thought, but if you're going to do that, please do it by asking a new question. The way this site works, you're not supposed to make major changes to a question that has already received an answer.  There's some wiggle room if the answerers aren't understanding what you are trying to ask, but I get the impression I did answer _this_ question... or did I?

Comment: Yes you did answer the question. Have to add that I need to handle several file I/O per user(client). It is good advise to use some event multiplexing libs, I just want to make something myself.

Comment: @zwol: Have you considered using [`poll()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) with zero `events` in chunks of, say, few hundred to a thousand descriptors, to find the open descriptors (within a specified range, or from 0 to `getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE)`)? The `revents` will be `POLLNVAL` for all non-open descriptors. Since `poll()` is POSIX.1-2001, it should be available in most Unixy systems.

Comment: @NominalAnimal No, I hadn't thought of that, that's clever, do you want to write a second answer describing that?

Comment: @zwol: To be honest, I've only used the Linux-only `/proc/self/fd/` scan myself. The `poll()` only came to me when I read your answer here, as I recently explored some `select()`/`poll()` code; I have not written an implementation of it, and I could only test it on Linux right now. I'd need to be able to test it on a few non-Linux systems first, to be sure I'm not talking garbage, before feeling confident enough to supply it as an answer. I was honestly hoping you'd have tried it, and had experience on it I could rely on! :)